# SUMX wont SUM when using two mesaures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this odd thing happening and I dont know why.
I have two mesaures named [_Credit] and [_Debit], what I am trying to do is to get these in one column and depending if value [Ak] is empty or not it should print [_Credit] otherwise [_Debit].

My DAX code looks like this:

```
SUMX('AL Dim_Org',
    IF(
       ISBLANK('AL Dim_Org'[Ak]),
        [_Credit],[_Debit])
    )
```

Now i only get the [_Debit] value printed and not the [_Credit] value.
But if I but in 0 and 1 as value to print it prints 0 and 1 depending on the condition.

**DAX Mesaures**

```
_Credit =
ROUND (
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'AL Dim_Org'[Ak] ),
        IF (
            VALUES ( 'AL Dim_Org'[Ak] ) = BLANK (),
            - (
                CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Cost] ), ALL ( 'AL Dim_Org'[Ak] ) )
                    - CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Cost] ), FILTER ( 'AL Fact', 'AL Fact'[Cost] <> BLANK () ) )
            )
        )
    ),
    0
)


_Debit =
ROUND (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( [Cost] ),
        FILTER ( 'AL Dim_Org', 'AL Dim_Org'[Activity] <> BLANK () )
    ),
    0
)
```

Here is a image of how the table is looking and i want everything to populate in the Mashup column.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide DAX code for the measures, and it'd be helpful if you post your data model diagram.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will update the post.

Comment: What do you expect `_Credit` to return for each row? To me, it looks like it would evaluate to `- ( [Cost] - [Cost] ) = 0` every time but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing your table.

Comment: @AlexisOlson The (-) just makes so there is a (-) in front of the value. cant the table since its in the backend. Its a direct query and the relations is build at the server side.

Comment: Regardless of where it’s calculated, it’s still iterating through each row and it would be useful to know what you expect if it’s not giving what you expect.

Comment: What I expect its just that it should take these two colums and display them as one column. I Will post a image in the post.

Comment: Does the following work for you Mashup = IF(ISBLANK([_Credit]) ,[_Debit], [_Credit])

Comment: @DarylWenman-Bateson Sometimes you make it more complex than it needs to be. Thanks. This worked really good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mashup = IF(ISBLANK([_Credit]) ,[_Debit], [_Credit])